# Implementing IActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building the below filter:

```
public class TestflowFilter : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var profileId = int.Parse(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetClaimValue("UserId"));
        var appId = int.Parse(filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());

        if (profileId != 0 && appId != 0)
        {
            if (CheckIfValid(profileId, appId))
            {
                 // redirect
                 filterContext.Result = // url to go to
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }

}
```

I actually only need `OnActionExecuted`, but since `IActionFilter` is an interface I have to implement them both. Is it ok to leave `OnActionExecuting` blank if I don't need anything to happen, or do I need to call a base version that MVC always runs?

Also in the `OnActionExecuted` method if the `CheckIfValid` is `true` I redirect the user, but if not I don't do anything. Is that ok or do I need to set some property on the `filterContext` instead.

Comment: It is not needed to populate `OnActionExecuting` with code. In case of `OnActionExecuted`, it is ok do not assign value to filterContext.Result, that means asp.net continues the normal life cycle pipeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I actually only need OnActionExecuted, but since IActionFilter is an interface I have to implement them both. Is it ok to leave OnActionExecuting blank if I don't need anything to happen, or do I need to call a base version that MVC always runs?

Leaving the method body empty is perfectly acceptable in this case. Looks good!

> Also In the OnActionExecuted method if the CheckIfValid is true I redirect the user, but if not I don't do anything, is that ok or do I need to set some property on the filterContext instead.

Your filter is fine. MVC does offer a different abstract base class called `ActionFilterAttribute`, which implements these interfaces for you to override as needed. There's a nice overview that you [can read about here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs). If you derive from that class, your filter attribute code could be simplified a little bit:

```
public class TestflowFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var profileId = int.Parse(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetClaimValue("UserId"));
        var appId = int.Parse(filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());

        if (profileId != 0 && appId != 0)
        {
            if (CheckIfValid(profileId, appId))
            {
                // redirect
                filterContext.Result = // url to go to
            }
        }
    }
}
```